# Creating random numbers with time out javascript

Tags: javascript, random, settimeout

Have a function thats emulated server request

```
function request(val, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  callback(val * val);}, Math.randInt(1000));}
```

val – integer value;
callback – function that will be executed after some random delay. It has one integer parameter.

I need folowing: generate number and emulate server timeout by this function

try to this

```
     <script>

       var a = function randomInteger(max) {
        var rand = 0 + Math.random() * (max + 1 - 0 -1);
        rand = Math.floor(rand);
        return rand;
        };
        function callback(dd) {
            var caaler = 20 + dd;
            return caaler;
        };
        var hh = callback(20)
        var q = a(50);
        var g = request(q,hh);
        function request(val, callback) {
      setTimeout(function() {
      callback(val * val);
  }, 3000);
}
console.log(callback(56));
        </script>
```

but have answer: Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function - after 3 seconds.
Need to generate number and after some timeout show it, using function at the top

and I dont understand what means Math**.randInt**(1000));

Comment: It's all a bit of a mess, where is the callback function defined?

Comment: function() {
      callback(val * val);

Comment: That isn't a function definition that's you calling function callback() and passing a parameter... a definition for a function named callback() would be something like:  function callback(param) { code; }

Comment: update code,please check. Thats probem is that I must use this function with some strange "callback" I dont understand why I must used? but I must...

Comment: Maybe you should learn what callbacks are and how they work before you try and use them? Sorry, really don't wish to be rude but your code is quite rough to say  the least. From your description of the callback and its use it would appear you have a poor understanding of the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. `console.log` needs to be called inside the callback.

```
function randInt(max) {
  var rand = Math.random() * max;
  rand = Math.floor(rand);
  return rand;
}

function request(val, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(val * val);
  }, randInt(1000));
}

request(20, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: How it's all do on button click? onclick="request()" or onclick="result()" ?

Comment: how to + two vars if there would be inside  request function?

Comment: Could you give me an example? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qty3aodr/
There I dublicate 3 request function. They have varialbles
a,b,c. I need plus this vars in to one variable and show it.

Answer (score 0):

You pass in one argument:

```
    var g = request(q);
```

to a function that's defined as needing 2:

```
    function request(val, callback) {'
```

which means that `callback` within that function will be undefined, hence your error. Perhaps you meant to pass in that `a` function you defined earlier.

Comment: I must define function callback somewhere early?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use this function, it's seems that you need to pass a number and a function (callback)

```
function request(val, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(val * val);
    }, 3000);
}
```

like this

```
request(50, a);
```

this is for example the function you wrote, that you can pass as the second parameter to the `request` function

```
var a = function randomInteger(max) {
    var rand = 0 + Math.random() * (max + 1 - 0 -1);
    rand = Math.floor(rand);
    console.log(rand);
};
```

in this function you can print the result to the screen